# Quest for a missing release of Apache Cloud Stack 4.7.1.3

Tags: cloud

Is there any public evidence of Apache Cloud Stack release 4.7.1.3?

Namely, what I can find so far, there is only 4.7.1.1, but an instance I can observe reports to be a 4.7.1.3.

See also:

https://github.com/apache/cloudstack/issues/3084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it came out, the instance is not Cloud Stack but [Cloud Platform by Citrix](https://www.shapeblue.com/citrix-cloudplatform/), (a commercial fork?) so they have slightly different version numbers.

I.e.:

- 4.7.1.3 of Cloud Platform depends on CS 4.7.1.1.
- 4.11 of Cloud Platform depends on CS 4.10..?